# What are the things that allow gaming chair wheels to rotate?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I was wondering if they were also called bearings, because I am not sure they look like bearings although I didn't specifically looked inside of a gaming chair to know whether they also use bearings to allow wheels to rotate freely.

Comment: You accidentally posted this question twice. Please delete one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The undriven wheels are called [*casters*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caster) They are mounted on *pivots* which allow them to rotate around their vertical axes. The wheels themselves contain bearings.

Comment: The word is usually spelled 'castor' in countries where British English is used.